# Hex string to hex char[]

Tags: c++, string, char, hex

I have an integer and want to get hex of this integer in form of char[].

example:

```
unsigned int i = 1234567890;
```

and I want to get the following char[]:

```
char hex[] = "\x49\x96\x02\d2";  // hex of i;
```

I can get hex as a string:

```
        std::stringstream sstream;
        sstream << std::hex << image_base_OEP;
        auto result =  sstream.str();
```

but that's not what I need.

Comment: @Barmar The integer is 0x499602d2

Comment: Does std::string::c_str do what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking for a null-terminated string of printable and non-printable characters, HEX does not enter into the picture: the four characters in the string are simply the four bytes of `i`'s representation, which you can get as follows:

```
char hex[] = {
    (i >> 24) & 0xFF
,   (i >> 16) & 0xFF
,   (i >>  8) & 0xFF
,   (i >>  0) & 0xFF
,   0 // Null terminator to match your C string
};
```

Note that it is probably a good idea to make `i` and `hex` unsigned.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/YkoAQc)

Comment: You should note that it's best for `i` to be `unsigned`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, thank you, that's what I need. 
Playing with bits is always awesome.

Comment: @Barmar Right. Making `hex` unsigned would do the trick, too. I edited the answer, thank you very much!

Comment: Now rename the variable because calling it `hex` is extremely misleading

Comment: be careful, as the `0` value can be interpersed in the integer, for example if you have the number `65536`, it should convert into `"\x01\x00\x00"`, and the final result should be wrong, as you have the delimiter inside your string, acting as the delimiter, you'll get `"\x01"`, not the expected value.